# creating XML file inside WEB-INF

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

Im using http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/ to create a map of my website, currently i have a lot of links and i cant write all the rules by hand, example:

```
<rule>
   <from>^/about-us$</from>
   <to type="redirect">/myWeb/Controller?page=ForwardAbout</to>
</rule>
```

Tuckey uses a file called `urlrewrite.xml` inside WEB-INF folder.

The redirect rules could come from a database, for example: whenever an article is created, insert a row to the desired link like:

```
/about-potatoes
```

And the rule would become this

```
<rule>
   <from>^/about-us$</from>
   <to type="redirect">/myWeb/Controller?page=ForwardPotatoes</to>
</rule>
```

Then the `urlrewrite.xml` should be written so the redirect to the new article applies.

**The main question is:** How can I create this `urlrewrite.xml` inside WEB-INF?

**Secondary question:** Suposing that new articles are made every week, creating this `urlrewrite.xml` every week to update the rules, would the rules apply without having to re-deploy the web-app again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On most application servers, you can't dynamically change anything inside the web application, unless you re-package and re-deploy the application.

Even if you could change the file, e.g. in unpacked wars, tuckey will probably still read the file only once, and not pick up the new rules unless you restart the application.

Why don't you make a more dynamic rule that matches all requests? In the rewrite rule you can use backreferences e.g. '$1' that will match the first regular expression that is between brackets, like:

```
<rule>
   <from>^/about-(.*)$</from>
   <to type="redirect">/myWeb/Controller?page=Forward$1</to>
</rule>
```

Comment: i was thinking of this also, but the problem is that the regular expression does not allways match the parameter on page=Forward, i think the easiest thing is to force them match, thanks